# Completely stop displaying a div by using conditionally rendering

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

There is this one thing that is bothering me. I have this one line of code which uses the "v-if" tag, it is used to hide one of the menu items after you've used a setup tool.

The problem here is that when you load up the page, it will display the menu item for half a second first which should be hidden directly from the start. How can I achieve this?

**Here is the code:**

```
                <li><button v-show="!configCompleted" class="btn" @click="setComponent('setup')">Setup</button></li>
```

**beforeMount lifecycle hook:**

```
beforeMount() {
    this.setComponent(this.$route.params.page)
    this.user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('vue-laravel-ecommerce. d fuser'))
    axios.defaults.headers.common['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
    axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('vue-laravel-ecommerce.jwt')
    axios.get('/api/shop').then( response => {
        if ( response.data.length ) {
            this.configCompleted = true
        }
    });
},
```

Comment: I can see that you are showing the button when `configCompleted` is `false`. Is that what you intend?

Comment: That is correct

Comment: Now, what is the value of `this.configCompleted` in `data () { return { configCompleted: true or false? } }`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you modify this.configCompleted when you get the response from api, which takes some time. You can probably just set the default value of it to true in data()

```
data() {
    return {
        configCompleted: true,
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: That was also my guess, but I wasn't really sure. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: I checked if the config was already completed before setting it true so it makes sense, doing it the other way around did it indeed.